# Cannot get ruby bluepill gem to install on ubuntu

Tags: process, ruby

i install bluepill on ubuntu: Linux auto 2.6.31-14-server #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 15:07:34 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Actual Result:

```
root@auto:/# gem install bluepill
Successfully installed bluepill-0.0.43
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...
Installing RDoc documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...
root@auto:/# bluepill
bluepill: command not found
root@auto:/#
```

I install bluepill on ubuntu: Linux autobot 2.6.27-7-server #1 SMP Tue Nov 4 20:18:35 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux

`stdout:`

gem install bluepill Successfully installed blankslate-2.1.2.3 Successfully installed state_machine-0.9.4 Successfully installed bluepill-0.0.43 3 gems installed Installing ri documentation for blankslate-2.1.2.3... Installing ri documentation for state_machine-0.9.4... Installing ri documentation for bluepill-0.0.43... Installing RDoc documentation for blankslate-2.1.2.3... Installing RDoc documentation for state_machine-0.9.4... Installing RDoc documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...

How come i can install bluepill on one ubuntu and cannot on the other, is bluepill OS version dependent ? or needs some libs that are missing ? on my Linux auto 2.6.31-14-server

Thanks,
-Kamal.

Answer (score 0):

Find binary file:

```
 find / -name bluepill
```

End execute(Ubuntu 10.04 + ruby1.8)

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bluepill
```

Change PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/
```